# Comparing 2 Integers in C++

Tags: c++, operators, equality

I get an error when I try to compare two integers in Qt.

```
if ((modus==2) & (move != -1))

error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator!='
```

Do I need other operators? I have googled but it seems that Qt uses the same. Thanks for your ansers

Comment: What type is `modus` and `move`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a C++0x compiler, `move` might conflict with `std::move()`. I'm thinking that's what's causing the "unresolved overloaded function type" part of the error message.

Comment: Thanks! Its conflicting with QPoint.

Answer (score 5):

You should use && for the and-operation:

```
if ((modus==2) && (move != -1))
```

Comment: I agree it would be better, but it shouldn't matter here. Binary AND gives the same result in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

The operator you're using (&) is a "binary and", not the "logical and" you seem to want (&&). Assuming both 'modus' and 'move' are of type int, it should work fine:

```
if (modus==2 && move!=-1) {
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you, but I found it. The variable "move" belongs to QPoint or something like this. I just renamed my varible and everything is doing fine. Thanks anyway.